# Mouse pointer decoration in JAVA project

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, mouse

I am working in a school project , So to make attract a child in my project I want to implement special mouse pointer. for example pointer like, where pointer moves a small bird will follow the pointer. I am doing project in java platform . so any links you guys know about this please let me know.

Comment: Are you doing Java or JavaScript? (These are _not_ the same language.)

Comment: I am working in JAVA project but any how I can use javascript in it na. .

Answer (score 0):

I can give some help .This is regarding a flying bird follow a button ,when hovering .You can refer to following link.Hope this would help you out :)

http://codepen.io/minimalmonkey/pen/ouwcn

And this would be helpful also, but it's widget

http://www.way2blogging.org/2011/01/how-to-add-animated-flying-twitter-bird.html

Comment: ya it was fine . . , is there any other links .